# Handle exception thrown from a CDI interceptor as a faces message

Tags: jsf, exception, cdi, interceptor

I want to show exception message in xhtml. Execption is generated in interceptor.

Interceptor  class :

```
    @Logable
    @Interceptor
    public class LoggingInterceptor
    {
        @AroundInvoke
        public Object log(InvocationContext ctx)
            throws Exception {
            if (some logic)
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("newBandForm:ABCD", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "hklfhfhsf", "hklfhfhsf"));
                throw new Exception("MNOP");
            return ctx.proceed();
    }
```

Action Bean Class

```
@Named("bcontroller")
@RequestScoped
public class BandListController
{
   @Logable
    public void save()
    {
    }
}
```

I want to show exception in xhtml p:message

```
<h:form id="newBandForm">
    <p:messages id="ABCD" autoUpdate="false" closable="true" showDetail="false" escape="false"/>
</h:form>
```

If I write following line in Action "save()" itself, and remove Interceptor, then message i getting displayed.

```
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("newBandForm:ABCD", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "hklfhfhsf", "hklfhfhsf"));
```

It seems that exception thrown is interrupting life-cycle of JSF components also. 

thanks

### Detail Requirement:

I have one xhtml page which contain one field (say : F1 )and two commandButton (say : C1 and C2). For C1 button, F1 is mandatory and For C2, it is not. This is completely configurable and at bean initialization, I fetch data from database for which button, what fields are mandatory.

Now on finding @Logable annotation, I am invoking interceptor method for checking data consistency based on action. In case validation failed, I have to set p:message (for which I am accessing FaceContext).

Why am i doing like this? So that a single annotation can enable security without changing code of  main action.

I end up with in javax "interceptor" after searching "aop in JSF". I do not have option of implementing spring-aop in project.

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding the concrete functional requirement. You're throwing an exception instead of proceeding and then you're "complaining" that JSF lifecycle is interrupted. What exactly did you expect? Why exactly are you throwing an exception while you apparently want to proceed? Trying to grab the `FacesContext` inside an interceptor is also alarming. It doesn't look like that you're using the right tool for the job. So, please elaborate the concrete functional requirement for which you thought that this all would be the right solution.

Comment: @BalusC, Thanks for replying. just few minute ago, I replaced  exception from 'return  null'. and it worked. I will update the question.

Comment: or should i write a answer for same ??

Comment: @BalusC, I have added my requirement. Is any better method exist for achieving same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My lack of understanding about "ctx.proceed()" lead me to this problems.What it do is "Proceed to the next interceptor in the interceptor chain." and if there is non, flow will resume as usual.

(Workaround) Changing code like this solve my issue:

```
@AroundInvok
public Object log(InvocationContext ctx)
    throws Exception {
    if (!(some logic))
    {
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
    else
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("newBandForm:ABCD", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "hklfhfhsf", "hklfhfhsf"));
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Now I am not throwing any exception from it.